# Why won't sfValidatorDoctrineChoice validate?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm trying to set a drop down to 'required' but the form still goes through. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
this->exportForm = new sfForm();
$widgets['sheet_type'] = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => 'ExportSheet', 'add_empty' => true));
$this->exportForm->setWidgets($widgets);
$this->exportForm->setValidators(array('sheet_type' => new sfValidatorDoctrineChoice(array('model' => 'ExportSheet', 'required' => true), array('required' => 'Please select a sheet type to export.') )));
```

UPDATE:

I've made the changes suggested.

actions.class.php:

```
$this->exportForm      = new sfForm();
$this->exportForm->getWidgetSchema()->setNameFormat('exportForm[%s]');
$widgets['sheet_type'] = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => 'ExportSheet', 'add_empty' => true));

$this->exportForm->setWidgets($widgets);
$this->exportForm->setValidators(array('sheet_type' => new sfValidatorDoctrineChoice(array('model' => 'ExportSheet', 'required' => true), array('required' => 'Please select a sheet type to export.') )));


if ($request->isMethod('post'))
{
    $this->exportForm->bind($request->getParameter('exportForm'));

        if ($this->exportForm->isValid())
        {
                        ...
                    }
}
```

Template:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo url_for('@export'); ?>">
<div id="export" style="display: block"> 
<?php echo $exportForm['sheet_type']->renderRow(); ?>
</form>
```

I can see when I submit that the echoing $request->getParameter('sheet_type') does return a value. If this is the case, why is the validation still failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 parts to validating a form ... the first is adding the validators the second is checking if its valid ....

take this example :

```
public function executeSomeaction(sfWebRequest $request)
{
   // Define the form
   this->exportForm = new sfForm();
   $widgets['sheet_type'] = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => 'ExportSheet', 'add_empty' => true));
   $this->exportForm->setWidgets($widgets);
   $this->exportForm->setValidators(array('sheet_type' => new sfValidatorDoctrineChoice(array('model' => 'ExportSheet', 'required' => true), array('required' => 'Please select a sheet type to export.') )));

  // Deal with the request
  if ($request->isMethod('post'))
  {
    $this->exportForm->bind($request->getParameter(<your form>));
    if ($this->exporForm->isValid())
    {
      // Handle the form submission
      // ...

      $this->redirect('foo/bar');
    }
  }
}
```

Its only the second part within `if ($request->isMethod('post'))` that applies your validation and checks the user submitted data. [See here in the symfony docs](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/10-Forms#chapter_10_sub_form_handling_with_data_validation) about handling forms with validation

If you use the following to add a naming schema for your form output then getting all of the results is easy ....

```
$this->exportForm->getWidgetSchema()->setNameFormat('exportForm[%s]');
```

then you can get use :

```
$this->exportForm->bind($request->getParameter('exportForm'));
```

this will then get the array with all of the field values in it and bind it to your form - ready for checking to see if its valid.

### Update

you need to specify

```
$this->exportForm->getWidgetSchema()->setNameFormat('exportForm[%s]');
```

after

```
$this->exportForm->setWidgets($widgets);
```

as the `setWidgets` method resets the naming format

Comment: @Roy no probs ... the manual for symfony is brilliant - i read it cover to cover at least 3 times before even began to code ....

Comment: I was too quick to reply - it doesn't work despite doing the bind. I have no idea what's going on!

Comment: @Roy update your question with more of you code (action and view) and anything from the logs that is useful.

Comment: I just did. Do you see any problems?

Comment: I solved it. There was an issue with the bind() call. Doing this:

    $this->exportForm->bind(array('sheet_type' => $request->getParameter('sheet_type')));

...Solved the issue. I'm not entirely sure why that is, but at least it works!

Comment: this should be your bind line : `$this->exportForm->bind($request->getParameter('exportForm'));` see my answer (not updated !)

Comment: But that's what I did! You can see it in my updated question. That didn't work, but explicitly setting the variable in the bind worked. I don't get it.

Comment: @Roy you need to set the naming schema after you do `setWidgets` as the `setWidgets` method resets the naming schema .... updated my answer !